# Cordova and Sencha Touch

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch

I just created a Cordova App and have some html and JS files inside www folder. Now I want to add Sencha Touch UI Framework. What I want is to have the html and JS files as it is (from www folder) and build using Sencha Touch. Later on I will be adding Sencha UI stuff.

Any idea on how can I proceed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you would not start that way. You would create a sencha app..

```
sencha app generate MyApp myAppFolder
```

then change into the sencha touch folder

```
cd myAppFolder
sencha cordova init
```

then change into the cordova folder

```
cd cordova
cordova platform add android (plugins ....)
```

go back into the sencha root folder

```
cd ..
sencha app build native
```

that's it.

---

EDIT:
To go for the comment.
You can add an NTFS link (hard link) from the following folder:

```
senchaRoot/build/package/www
```

You can write into that folder automatically from the Sencha build process if you edit the file:

```
appRoot/.sencha/app/defaults.properties
```

change the following line:

```
build.dir=${workspace.build.dir}/${build.environment}/www
```

Comment: Thanks ... Yaa I have started that way only. But could not figure out where to put html files (from www folder). The requirement is to add a UI framework layer but not use it for the time being. Just for the sake of architecture design I have to add that layer. 

So, can you please guide how to add those www folder content. I have created cordova folder (by using init) then pasted the old www folder contents. And on App startup I want the index.html that is inside www folder. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I tried it and still getting same default landing page. I mean the 3 waiting dots and then Welcome to sencha screen.

I have copied the www folder contents to sencharoot/build/package/www. Then edited the default.properties

cordova contents were in sencharoot/cordova/www

Sorry for the trouble. I am very new to Sencha. Thanks a lot for guidance. Let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: do not copy anything to Sencha touch folder. simply change the default.properites file and run "sencha app build package". the content of this folder goes into the cordova "www" folder. That's what I would use a hardlink for (so you don't have to copy it every time). Then make a new build